# How to specify a record with a date greater than another date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a record called Feeds that contains the field 'last_visited' and 'last_modified', both are timestamps.

I'm trying to render a list in a view of alls Feeds where last_modified > last_visited.

I currently have this:

Controller

```
@feeds = @user.feeds

@feeds_hot = @feeds.where(['@feeds.last_modified > ?', @feeds.last_visited])
```

Have a feeling I'm way off track here. Should I also being using a model class to do this?

Any helps is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Here's my model

```
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :feed_id, :feed_url, :last_modified, :title, :url, :last_visited, :user_id

  belongs_to :user

  scope :hottest, lambda {where('last_modified > ?', :last_visited)}

  def fetch_feed!
   feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url) # probably want some eror handling here
   self.title = feed.title
   self.url = feed.url
   self.last_modified =  feed.last_modified
   self.last_visited  =  feed.last_modified
   self #or nil if you like
  end

  def self.check_for_update(feed)

    fetched_feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed.feed_url)

    entry = fetched_feed.entries.first
    feed.last_modified = entry.published

  end

 def update_visit_date!
  date = Time.now
  update_attribute(:last_visited, date)
  self
 end

end
```

**Edit**

Updated code

Controller

```
def home
  @user = current_user
  @feeds = @user.feeds
  @feeds_hot = @feeds.hottest
end
```

Model

```
attr_accessible :feed_id, :feed_url, :last_modified, :title, :url, :last_visited, :user_id

belongs_to :user

scope :hottest, lambda {where("'last_modified' > ?", 'last_visited')}
```

View

```
%ol.feeds.feeds_hot
  - @feeds_hot.each do |feed|
    %li.feed.hot[feed]
      = render :partial => 'feeds/feed_link', :locals => {:feed => feed}
```

Unfortunately it's still not rendering the hot feeds in the view when I have a feed with the following data:

```
Last Modified 2013-06-14 23:49:07 UTC
Last Visited 2013-06-14 23:47:55 UTC
```

Last Modified is a few hours > than Last Visited

Comment: Something does look right with a `Feed` having a `last_visited` field. Shouldn't that be tied to a user or a combination of feed-user?

Comment: Are you trying to get a list of all feeds that have been modified more recently than the most recent visit on any feed? Or are you simply trying to get a list of feeds where each one has been modified since it was last visited?

Comment: @zeantsoi I'm trying to get a list of feeds, showing only those where the modified date is more recent the the last visited date... Are you thinking there's might be a better approach?

Comment: @cupcakekid, what database and Rails version are you on? This works for me on SQLite and Rails 3.2. Depending on your environment, the single quote around `last_visited` in the SQL query might be throwing things off. Have a look at the amended syntax in my answer; it should add quotes around `last_modified`, which might make things work.

Comment: @zeantsoi I'm using Postgres and Rails 3.2. I'm not getting any errors anymore thanks to your quotes suggestion. Though unfortunately it's still not rendering the hot links, it's as though it doesn't recognise the date/time... see my code update for breakdown...

Comment: @zeantsoi Same thing when I run .hottest on the loop in the view

Comment: Wow... well, I'm nearly out of ideas. I think this is probably something related to Postgres. My last thought (shown below) is to force the SQL statement to look up `'feeds'.'last_modified' > 'feeds'.'last_visited'`, rather than `'last_modified' > 'last_visited'`. See if it works?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31789/discussion-between-zeantsoi-and-cupcakekid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to get a list of all feeds that have been modified more recently than the most recent visit on *any* feed, the following will work:

```
last_visit = Feed.order("last_visited").last.last_visited

@feeds = @user.feeds
@hot_feeds = Feed.where("last_modified > ?", last_visited)
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments and a re-reading of your question, the code posted above will not accomplish what you're trying to do. Since you're trying to get a list of all invites where each has been modified since it was last visited, you'll want to create a model `scope` to do the lookup with ActiveRecord. The following code should work:

```
# app/models/feed.rb
class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
scope :hottest, lambda {where('last_modified > ?', :last_visited)}
end
```

Then, you can run the following in a console, controller, or view:

```
@user.invites.hottest
#=> array of all the user's invites that have been modified more recently than they have been viewed
```

Comment: is right. There's no way to do it with rails, only this way or pure sql.

Comment: There are a few feeds not render where I know last_modified > last_visit = true. They'yre greater by an hour or 2, would it be more accurate if I used '.to_i' ? If so how do I used this in the where string?

Comment: @cupcakekid, see the answer in my update and let us know if it works.

Comment: @zeantsoi Thanks for the update, we're on the same page now :) But I'm receiving this error (last_modified and last_visited are timestamps): 

PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "last_visited"
LINE 1: ... WHERE "feeds"."user_id" = 1 AND (last_modified > 'last_visi...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds"  WHERE "feeds"."user_id" = 1 AND (last_modified > 'last_visited')

Comment: @cupcakekid, can you post your model to your question?

Comment: @zeantsoi Sure, see above^^